# Unable to hide a imag using .hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following view inside my asp.net mvc , which display a ajax-loading imag, which i am trying to hide after starting a jquery function as follow:-

```
<div id= "geturl" data-url="@Url.Action("ListPackages", "Home")">
<h1>All Processes</h1>
    <img id="tobehide" src="~/Content/ajax-loading2.gif" />
<ul id="products">
</ul>
```

Then the following JavaScript file:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#geturl').data('url'),
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            $('#tobehide').hide();
            $.each(result.data, function (key, val) {
                var str = val.packageName;
                $('<li/>', { text: str })
                    .appendTo($('#products'));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Currently the data will be filled in the  but the loading-imag will not be hiden.so how i can force the imag to hide when the java script starts executing?.
Best Regards

Comment: there may be some error, i tried to hide image without ajax code and it is working

Comment: check your image id after it is got rendered try giving it class instead

Comment: Verify that `$('#tobehide')` returns something.  It seems odd that hide wouldn't be working.

Comment: You don't have any other elements with that id? And ASP isn't changing the id before it gets to the browser? (Check the actual output as seen in the browser with View Page Source.)

Comment: what does $.each do? Shouldn't you have some elements selected? Also each is only supposed to be passed a handler, from what I can make of the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: @Asad - You're thinking of the wrong `.each()`. The [`$.each()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) iterates over the array or object that you pass it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct, and should work fine!
Try using FireBug or Chrome developer tools to see what's the javascript error you are getting back from the ajax call.
If that still doesn't help, and you want the image to be hidden regardless, then use the 'complete' callback on the jquery ajax call you are using.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#geturl').data('url'),
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        complete: function (result) {
            $('#tobehide').hide();
            $.each(result.data, function (key, val) {
                var str = val.packageName;
                $('<li/>', { text: str })
                    .appendTo($('#products'));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Also suspect either an ID collision on `#tobehide` or a typo since the OP states "Currently the data will be filled" (I read this as the success callback is being called).

Comment: that probably shouldn't work, since the data **is** being filled, and the code to do that is in the same handler.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine. No mistake in your code Brother.

try adding async option. Set it to false. and try again

Comment: async doesn't really matter - if there is an error in the ajax, which is probably the case, then the success callback won't be triggered anyhow...